# getcontent() is truncating the page content

Tags: android, file-get-contents

Can anyone help here. It was working correctly till an hour back but suddenly stopped working correctly (may be the web page content got modified with more information).

I am writing the page source code(http://bkdrluhar.com/00-htm/Daily%20Murlis.htm) into file test.txt. But suddenly it started truncating the contents. The file test.txt is truncated !

Below is my code. Please suggest if you find something.

```
protected void processMurlis(){
try {
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://bkdrluhar.com/00-htm/Daily%20Murlis.htm");
    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
    is = httpEntity.getContent();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"));
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/"+"test.txt"));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        currString = line.trim();
        sb.append(currString);
    } 
    bw.write(sb.toString());
    is.close(); 
    reader.close();
}catch(Exception e){
    errorMsg += "\nError: "+e.toString();
}
}
```